# CodeNarc TrailingWhitespace doesn't work properly on windows

Tags: groovy, codenarc

I use CodeNarc rule "TrailingWhitespace" to prevent whitespaces characters on the end of line.
This work fine on linux systems, but on windows when I leave whitespace on the end then check doesn't find this.
I use the same configuration for both systems, codenarc in gradle project.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got answer from codeNarc on github that problem is repaired in version 1.1